# Can't call history search in pry

Tags: ruby, macos, pry

I want to use `reverse-i-search` in Pry, but somehow I can't use in my OS X machine running iTerm2.

When I connect to VPS and run `pry`, then I can use the history search by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

It looks like the problem is located in my local environments, but I don't know what's wrong. I don't have a `~/.pryrc` config file.

What can I do to find out the cause of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `libedit` library problem (which replaces `readline` in modern MacOS distros.)

You need to explicitely configure `libedit`. Add to your `~/.editrc` this line:

```
bind "^R" em-inc-search-prev
```

For other issues see `man editrc`.